# Firebase realtime database always return null on reads

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write test android-app using firebase backend. 
I made all settings according to tutorials (using Google sign-in for auth and auth-checking rules for root object in realtime database) but still can not make firebase return something but nulls in snapshot's value (when onDataChange() is called). 
I'm sure that path and other settings are valid - otherwise I get "Permission Denied" in onCancelled() callback.
What can I do wrong?

Code:

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("api");
    mDatabase.child("test")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot
                                                 dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        //code that's never called
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError
                                                databaseError) {
                    //log error
                }
            });
```

Dependecies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

Data structure:

```
{"test" : true}
```

Snapshot's toString() result:

```
DataSnapshot { key = test, value = null }
```

The only one thing I could retrieve successfully from Firebase (if it does matter) is:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
```

Database rules:

```
    {"rules": {
"api":{
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
}}}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are your Database Rules set to read: true, write: true?

Comment: There are two reasons that this could be happening, either your rules do not comply with what you intend to do or your database structure is different from what you're trying to implement it as, in this code. Look into those aspects.

Comment: I've updated my question with current rules - I checked my paths with this rules in web-console simulator - everything looks fine, read is allowed, but I've noticed that data attribute in simulator respose was also null (but maybe it's fine for simulator): 
Type read
Location /api/test
Data null
Auth { "provider": "google", "uid": "53534d75-a8c2-440c-8c11-6cd043f415d8" }
Admin false

Answer (score 1):

I understood my falt. I was considering root path (firebase project id in web-console data-tree) as meaningful part of data path and try to point it in data query and security rules.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialised you database instance like this.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("api");
```

That means now all other references with `mDatabase` variable processed on `api` node.

So that means if you are calling below method,

```
mDatabase.child("test")
        . addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

That simple means it is looking for `api/test` path. But you have `test` node on root of database.

So modify initialisation of `mDatabase` variable like below and it'll work as you expect.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Source: [getReference("${String}")](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getReference(java.lang.String))